# AmazonS3 getUrl got a invalid reserved URL string?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

We have an initialized AmazonS3 object named "s3Client". When we call s3Client.getUrl(bucket, key) we got a string back a URL object. And when we do url.toString we got:

```
https://our.bucket.s3.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/key
```

which is not a valid URL, what works and should have been generated should be:

```
https://s3.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/our.bucket/key
```

Does anyone have any idea?

Comment: Can you please show us your code?

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue was I have a dot "." in my bucket name. SSL/TLS only supports a single level wild card cert. So a cert for *.s3.amazonaws.com is valid for bucket.s3.amazonaws.com but not our.bucket.s3.amazonaws.com. I can use the old style of addressing like s3.amazonaws.com/our.bucket